# Getting some errors during crossing compile PHP-5.5.9 for Android

Tags: php, android-ndk

I have crossed compile PHP-5.5.9.
Unfortunately, I got some errors during crossing compile.
The errors said : Makefile:574: recipe for target 'ext/standard/dns.lo'
failed
I don't know this message means.Please help me , thanks.

Here is the android-configure. It's a bash script file

```
!/bin/bash
export TOOLCHAIN=/home/lab501/android-toolchain
export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
./configure \
    --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
    --target=arm \
    -prefix=/home/lab501/php-5.5.9/_install \
    --with-iconv=/home/lab501/libiconv-1.14/_install \
    --with-libxml-dir=/home/lab501/libxml2-2.7.6/_install \
    --enable-simplexml \
    --enable-libxml \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-fpm \
    --without-zlib \
    --without-pear \
    --disable-mbregex \
```

Here is the screenshot during crossing compile PHP-5.5.9 when I got some
error messages.

[error message  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcITG.png)

Can anybody help me ? Thanks.

[solution]

I changed version to PHP-5.6.17 and It crossed compile successfully.

Herer is my bash script file for auto conf.

```
#!/bin/bash

export TOOLCHAIN=/home/lab501/android-toolchain
export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib

./configure \
  --prefix=/home/lab501/php-5.6.17/_install \
  --enable-static \
  --disable-shared \
  --disable-all \
  --enable-filter \
  --enable-calendar \
  --enable-ctype \
  --enable-dom \
  --enable-exif \
  --enable-fileinfo \
  --enable-ftp \
  --with-mhash="/home/lab501/mhash-0.9.9.9/_install" \
  --disable-intl \
  --disable-phar \
  --enable-posix \
  --enable-shmop \
  --enable-simplexml \
  --disable-sysvmsg \
  --enable-sysvsem \
  --disable-sysvshm \
  --enable-tokenizer \
  --disable-wddx \
  --enable-xmlreader \
  --enable-xmlwriter \
  --enable-pcntl \
  --enable-soap \
  --enable-cgi \
  --enable-json \
  --with-zlib \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
  --enable-mysqlnd \
  --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
  --enable-pdo \
  --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
  --enable-libxml \
  --with-pdo-sqlite \
  --with-sqlite3 \
  --enable-sockets \
  --enable-bcmath \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --enable-mbregex \
  --enable-session \
  --disable-ipv6 \
  --enable-opcache=no \
  --disable-cli \
  --without-pear \
  --enable-fpm \
  --enable-hash \
  --with-bz2="/home/lab501/bzip2-1.0.6/_install" \
  --with-zlib-dir="/home/lab501/zlib-1.2.8/_install" \
  --with-libxml-dir="/home/lab501/libxml2-2.7.6/_install" \
  --with-curl="/home/lab501/curl-7.35.0/_install" \
  --with-openssl="/home/lab501/openssl-1.0.1f/_install" \
  --with-jpeg-dir="/home/lab501/jpeg-9/_install" \
  --with-png-dir="/home/lab501/libpng-1.6.9/_install" \
  --with-freetype-dir="/home/lab501/freetype-2.5.3/_install" \
  --with-iconv-dir="/home/lab501/libiconv-1.14/_install" \
  --with-mcrypt="/home/lab501/libmcrypt-2.5.8/_install" \
  --with-pcre-dir="/home/lab501/pcre-8.34/_install" \
  --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

This [link](http://andynetnet.blog.chinaunix.net/uid-14735472-id-5230202.html) for solving my all problems during crossing compile PHP-5.6.17.

Comment: Please post the actual text of the error message and not an image. We can't copy paste from an image.

Comment: I have tried to build PHP for many times.
Finally, It worked successfully. Thanks everyone again.

Comment: You should leave the solution as an answer to your question. There's nothing worse for someone coming here from google than knowing that you found a solution but not knowing what it was: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I got it, but this solution was very tricky. I use PHP-5.6.16 that error was not presented, but I got another error. I wiil find available time to write the solution to this problems.